# Extract co ordinates from string

Tags: java

How does one extract both the numbers; listed below, individually from the string `(1,2)` in java.

```
String s="(1,2)";
```

and the output should be:

```
int x=1;
int y=2;
```

Or whatever numbers are listed inside of the string. . .

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself?

Comment: Ok Boss.. I am very sorry..Please remove your negative points Its my humble request to all of you..

Comment: @DeepakSharma - a simple regex with `//d+` will do it for you.

Comment: Why are you parsing this string? If it's coming from outside, that's fine, but if it's the `toString()` representation of a class you control, you should be adding getters for the values rather than parsing the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(1,2)";
    System.out.println("x=" + s.substring(1, s.indexOf(",")));
    System.out.println("y=" + s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1, s.length()-1));
}
```

Will give the following output:

```
x=1
y=2
```

This will even work, if the numbers have more than one digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = " abc d 1234567890pqr 54897";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+([0-9]+)\\w+([0-9]+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    matcher.find();

    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this.

The following regex will work.

```
\((\d+),(\d+)\)
```

To try it out, go to [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Paste `\((\d+),(\d+)\)` in the 'Your regular expression' box.
Type a test string for example (123,4567) in the 'Your test string' box.

You should see your answer in the match groups.

In java, you will have to parse these matched Strings to convert to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Every character inside of a String is actually a char. So with that information, you can use a `foreach` loop, or a `for` which loops for however long the string is (`s.length();`).
 
The ASCII number characters' value range from 61 to 71.

You can do something like this:
`List<short> listOfStringNum = new ArrayList<>();
     char tempChar;
     //Loop
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        tempChar = s.charAt(i);
        if(tempChar >= 61 & tempChar <= 71) 
           listOfStringNum.add((short) Character.getNumericValue(tempChar));
     }
     //Then do whatever is desired with the list e.g.
     System.out.println("Location: ");
     System.out.println("X = " + listOfStringNum.get(0) + 
     "\nY = " + listOfStringNum.get(1));`

I hope this helped :)